# Plotly Python, how can I display cursor position on plot?

Tags: plotly-python

Is there a way to display the x,y coordinates of the cursor position at the bottom of a Plotly(python) figure?

Comment: using **dash** with appropriate callback

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I was hoping not to have to go to dash.

Comment: https://plotly.com/python/v3/cars-exploration/ figure widget - needs to be something that can do callbacks